# Stacking Cards in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently I am learning react native and I have some problem while I am making stack of the cards.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const position = new Animated.ValueXY();
    const panResponder = new PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
            position.setValue({ x: gesture.dx, y: gesture.dy })
        },
    });
    this.state = { panResponder, position, index: 0 };
}


renderCards() {
    if(this.state.index >= this.props.data.length) {
        return this.props.renderNoMoreCard();
    }

    return this.props.data.map((item, i) => {
        if( i < this.state.index) { return null}

        if(i === this.state.index) {
            return (
            <Animated.View  
            key={item.id}
            style={[ styles.cardStyle, this.getCardStyle()]}
            {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
        {this.props.renderCard(item)}
        </Animated.View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Animated.View key={item.id} style={styles.cardStyle}>
            {this.props.renderCard(item)}
            </Animated.View>
        ); 
    }).reverse();
}
render() {

    return(
        <View>
        {this.renderCards()}
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = {
    cardStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    top: 0,
}
};

export default Deck;
```

[image]

The title card 2 is showing instead of card 1 but when I swipe the card. Card 1 is removed from view and title is changed to 3.

Comment: I have founded the mistake that while using panResponder I was making a object                const `panResponder =  new PanResponder.create`  but the code should be                         **const panResponder = PanResponder.create** and by changing this single line  it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was that while using PanResponder which is use to  reconciles several touches into a single gesture. So, 
I was declaring  a object `const panResponder = new PanResponder.create`
but the code should be 
**const panResponder = PanResponder.create** and by Removing this single word "**new**"  it worked!